# Flask Create global response function to be called from every where in the web app

Tags: python, flask

new to flask , i have web app that containes few parts 
for example:

```
utils/ 
-- utils.py
db/ 
-- oracle.py 
main.py
```

My Question is how can i make global_response function/handler that can be called from : utils.py,oracle.py,main.py without threading problem
for example:
in utils.py

```
clas Utils():
  def A(self):
     return global_response("error","a")
```

oracle.py

```
 clas Utils():
      def ORA(self):
         return global_response("error ora","b")
```

main.py
 def some_fun(self):
        return global_response("error main","c")

and here is the response function which was in main.py but now needs to be called from any where :

```
def global_response(error_msg, title,*options):
    res = {"status": error_msg, "title": title}

    for option in options:
        res.update(option)

 return json.dumps(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a response function, you can create a custom response class which will replace `flask`'s builtin `Response` class. 
The class will inherit `flask`'s `Response` class, meaning:

```py
class GlobalResponse(Response):
    pass
```

In order to generate the generic response, you should call the `app.make_response` method.
You can view This [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/customizing-the-flask-response-class) for a walk through of how to create a response class.

*Side notes*

1. I would recommended you to check out `flask`'s `jsonify` function which wraps the `json.dumps` and is considered "stronger" (works for more cases).
2. You may want to look at `flask`'s `make_response` [method](https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.make_response).

Comment: thanks , yes i  read about this and it probly the right way , but im dealing with legacy code. and in my case i want to leave the response function as it just make it accesble from any where in the app